# Launching Python Debug with Arguments messes with file path

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, debugpy

I'm using VSCode on Windows, with the GitBash as integrated terminal. When I launch the Python Debugger with default configurations, it works fine, and I get this command executed on the terminal:

```bash
/usr/bin/env c:\\Users\\augus\\.Apps\\anaconda3\\envs\\muskit-env\\python.exe \
c:\\Users\\augus\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\\bundled\\libs\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher \
53684 -- E:\\muskit\\QuantumSoftwareTestingTools\\Muskit\\Muskit\\CommandMain.py
```

Notice the `\\` in the file path. Again, above works just fine.

The problem is when I add the `args` property to my `launch.json` configuration.

launch.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File with Arguments",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following command is executed on the terminal:

```bash
$  /usr/bin/env c:\Users\augus\.Apps\anaconda3\envs\muskit-env\python.exe \
c:\Users\augus\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher \
53805 -- E:\muskit\QuantumSoftwareTestingTools\Muskit\Muskit\CommandMain.py foo
```

```bash
/usr/bin/env: ‘c:Usersaugus.Appsanaconda3envsmuskit-envpython.exe’: No such file or directory
```

Notice that, instead of `\\`. it uses `\`, which causes the "No such file or directory".

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the issues on [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python) repository, it is being mentioned in multiple issues that git bash is not officially supported. For example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23008#issuecomment-1972618316):

> Note Gitbash isn't supported by Python extension, so use Select default profile to switch to cmd or powershell if need be.

Possibly it is a bug and it will be better to use cmd or powershell, since you can run into issues in the future as well.

Some related issues which mention the same

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3035
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23008
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22957